# How do I setup request tracker version rt5.0.3 's database at installation?

Tags: mysql

There's a bunch of chicken and egg problems with setting up rt5, and spending an hour hammering against doing this seems valuable to document for everyone else.

There are two specific issues:

- the database user to create doesnt exist so cant be used to create itself or any databases

  - if you create the user manually in mysql (and grant it permissions on say an rt5 database) it does not have permissions to create users which the ACL portion of the database initialization requires.
  - you need to grant INSERT privileges on mysql.* with grant option to the user to allow it to do so - but this is a security hole (especially if not removed).
- the schema to create the database does not exist in /opt/rt5/etc (default install dir)

(note all of the below is done as user root in a shell, equiv would be 'sudo' in front of each command if you prefer)

make initialize-database does not work as it reads /opt/rt5/etc/RT_SiteConfig.pm and find the db user (rt_admin) and tries to use its privileges to do everything (include create itself?)

Since the make command is just running /opt/rt5/sbin/rt-setup-database --action init, we can just run that manually with options after creating the user and database ourselves:

```
mysql> create database rt5;
mysql> grant all on rt5.* to 'rt_admin'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Then: /opt/rt5/sbin/rt-setup-database --action acl,coredata,insert

But that causes issues:

```
[24841] [Thu Dec 14 23:58:59 2023] [warning]: DBD::mysql::st execute failed: You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT at /opt/rt5/sbin/../lib/RT/Handle.pm line 475, <STDIN> line 1. (/opt/rt5/sbin/../lib/RT/Handle.pm:475)
```

This continues with various other errors. Even with GRANT privs we get:

```
[25007] [Fri Dec 15 00:10:13 2023] [warning]: DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Access denied for user 'rt_admin'@'localhost' to database 'mysql' at /opt/rt5/sbin/../lib/RT/Handle.pm line 475, <STDIN> line 1. (/opt/rt5/sbin/../lib/RT/Handle.pm:475)
```

Suggesting rt_admin needs mysql.* access with additional super-user level options.

Comment: SO is for programming and software development related queatuins, not to document installation instructions for random products!

Comment: my bad, but i found many other similar questions, and even my sidebar right now as i write this is filled with install and operation questions: "how to get sizes of my mysql database?" "error installing perl module for bugzilla" "access denied for user with password" "mysql shutdown unexpectedly" -- point me in the right direction if you can!

Comment: You are not the only one posting off topic questions...

Comment: Although access denied error often comes iup n programming context

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the first problem is to run rt-setup-database by hand (as root) from the /opt/rt5/etc dir:

(note: man page for rt-setup-database is here https://docs.bestpractical.com/rt/5.0.5/rt-setup-database.html )

```
../sbin/rt-setup-database --dba root --action acl,coredata,insert
```

If you are using a password for root mysql (default debian does not), then add a --prompt-for-dba-password to your command).

However, I recommend doing one action at a time to capture errors as they occur:

```
../sbin/rt-setup-database --dba root --action acl
../sbin/rt-setup-database --dba root --action coredata
```

This should work and create all the new users as required (be sure your rt-admin or whatever is in RT_SiteConfig.pm as a database user is created).

The second issue is that there is no default schema path for the *rt-setup-database --action insert* command. So a full path to a schema must be provided.

Why there isnt one for 5.0.3 is beyond me, and I stabbed into the dark and used the etc/upgrade/5.0.2 one (which seems to be specified by the 'content' code snip in that dir -- the insert action will fail with

```
 [critical]: Cannot open initialdata file '/opt/rt5/etc/content' for read:  at /opt/rt5/sbin/../lib/RT/Handle.pm line 872. (/opt/rt5/sbin/../lib/RT.pm:409)
```

otherwise.)

The solution is to insert with this command (again run from the /opt/rt5/etc dir):

../sbin/rt-setup-database --datadir=`pwd`/upgrade/5.0.2 --dba root --action insert

This solved my issues.